# Heroku update not showing on DNS

Tags: heroku, dns

My site is using DNS (http://playciv.com) and heroku url is https://civilization-boardgame-web.herokuapp.com

I have updated my site, but the changes are only showing when I use https://civilization-boardgame-web.herokuapp.com directly and not through my DNS.
Why is that?

How can I make the update show on my DNS? www.playciv.com

Comment: you need to be more specific. Do you mean flushing dns? browser cache? network cache etc etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I flushed my DNS and it worked!